# How to let Chroniker update my table in a cronjob?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an issue with my Postgresql database, I'm running my app in a container.
I have a custom command in my Django app working minutely, when it start, my custom command check how many proxies there are and get the max ID and choose a random one.

It works well, but something gone wrong after, when I check if the proxy didn't work in my script, I delete it from my database, my database accept to delete it, nothing gone wrong here.

One minute after, when the command start again my command think it have the same number of proxy, when I check my database, I've got one less, so after some minutes my app choose randomly a proxy id who didn't exist.

```py
from django.db.models import Max
import random


def get_proxy():
    max_id = Proxy.objects.all().aggregate(max_id=Max("id"))['max_id']
    print(max_id)
    while True:
        pk = random.randint(1, max_id)
        proxy = Proxy.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
        if proxy:
            return proxy
```

When the issue append for example max_id return 680, whereas I've got only 600 id in my database.

```
None
max_id

The job failed to run.  The exception was :

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chroniker/models.py", line 1055, in handle_run
    call_command(self.command, *args, **options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 148, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

  File "/code/scraper/management/commands/get_ads.py", line 106, in handle
    scrape()

  File "/code/scraper/management/commands/get_ads.py", line 30, in scrape
    proxy = get_proxy()

  File "/code/scraper/management/commands/get_ads.py", line 21, in get_proxy
    pk = random.randint(1, max_id)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 222, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I'm using this package for the cronjob https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker
Sorry if I miss something in the configuration.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `Max("id")` will only get smaller if you delete the proxy with the highest id. If you delete a randomly selected proxy, it will most likely stay the same.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, didn't know that.
I have right another function to solve this.
def get_proxy():
    count = Proxy.objects.aggregate(count=Count('id'))['count']
    print('count = ' + str(count))
    random_index = random.randint(0, count - 1)
    return Proxy.objects.all()[random_index]

Comment: If you want to write an answer Daniel, for closing this post :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler `get_proxy()` method:

```
def get_proxy():
    all_proxy_ids = Proxy.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
    if not all_proxy_ids:
        raise ValueError("No proxies available")
    random_proxy_id = random.choice(proxy_ids)
    return Proxy.objects.get(id=random_proxy_id)
```

Here is what it does:

- fetch the ids of all Proxy objects as list.
- if the list is empty, meaning there are no proxies, an exception is raised.
- pick a random id from the list.
- get the Proxy object for this random id.

This will get slow if you have millions of Proxy objects in your database, but it should work fine for a few thousand.

Note that you still have to ensure that the job does not run twice at the same time.